# How can I use mysqli fetch_assoc() several times with prepared statements on same PHP page?

Tags: php, mysqli, associative-array

Is there a way to enable the use of `fetch_assoc()` several times on the same page with prepared statements?

```
    $data = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id=?");
    $data->bind_param('i',$id);
    $data->execute();
    $result = $data->get_result();
```

I'd like to be able to use `fetch_assoc()` on the same page as many times as I want as many different ways I want. If I want to loop twice, I should be able to do that. If I want to loop and do a single fetch, I should also be able to do that. Right now it seems, once `fetch_assoc()` is being used once, it cannot be used again on the same page.

**In a loop**

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
...
}
```

**Single fetch**

```
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();
$first_name = $user['first_name'];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`mysqli_result::data_seek`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) to reset the result pointer after each usage so you can loop over the results multiple times. For example:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
...
}
$result->data_seek(0);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

While technically possible (Nick shows how) to rewind the `mysqli_result` object, many people find it cumbersome to work with `mysqli_result` at all. It's much easier to fetch all the records into a PHP array and work with a multidimensional array instead of the `mysqli_result` object.

```
$result = $data->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

This way you can do whatever you want with this array. You can filter, you can loop many times, you can use all the standard array functions in PHP.

```
$resultsFiltered = array_filter($results, fn($e) => $e['someColumn']>200);
foreach($resultsFiltered as $row) {
    // only records with someColumn > 200
}
```